# Function Overloading: Terminology for different types of overloaded functions?

Tags: java, function, methods, overloading, terminology

For example, say I have these 3 overloaded functions:

```
/** Function #1 */
public static String add(List<String> operands)
{
    return add(operands, 10);
}

/** Function #2 */
public static String add(List<String> operands, int base)
{

    return Integer.toString(add(Integer.parseInt(operands.remove(0), base),operands, base), base);
}

/** Function #3 */
private static int add(int result, List<String> operands, int base)
{
    if(operands.size() == 0)
    {
        return result;
    }

    result += Integer.parseInt(operands.remove(0), base);

    return add(result, operands, base);
}
```

Would it be correct to call Function #2 in this case the "parent" overloaded function of Function #1 because Function #1 calls it and both are public?

Would it also be correct to call Function #3 the "recursive" function of these functions, or is there another term to describe the fact that it is called by the public functions as a hidden function that recursively calls itself?

I know those will not be the correct terms, but what I am trying to get at is whether there is set terminology for the different types of overloaded functions given their role.

Comment: side note: Functions in java should be camelCase.

Comment: If a method is `public` and part of your API, then you should expect that it may be used.

Comment: @Ahmad Thanks, corrected. It gets hectic at times switching from C# to Java on a daily basis.

Comment: Interesting question; but I am not aware of any "de-facto" terms that everybody would agree on here. I think you are correct in expressing that there are certain relations between those three methods; but AFAIK those concepts go "unnamed". So in that sense, as interesting as it feels; my feeling is that this question is "border-line" to be "asking for opinions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be reluctant to define any terms that the Java Language Specification doesn't.

Simply put your have 3 functions, 2 `public` and 1 `private`. They have the same *name* but different parameter types, so they are *overloads*.

Indeed a function that calls itself is a *recursive* function. The JLS does define that term since Java compilers must support functions that call themselves.

Don't refer to one of your functions as the "parent overload" - it's not particularly helpful, and your use of the term "abstraction" is idiosyncratic.

Comment: "idiosyncratic" is my word of the day

Comment: How about "floccinaucinihilipilification" for tomorrow? (The longest word ever spoken in the UK parliament).

Comment: I've been trying to pronounce this under my breath for a couple minutes. My co-workers might think I'm a crazy person now.

Comment: I am inclined to say "Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo"!

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks. My goal was to see if there was a term, or some sort of short-hand way of explaining the role of each overloaded function in the comment documentation of my code for another project. But I'll keep it to the JLS to be universally understandable.

Answer (score 0):

For this case I do not there is a specific term; however there is a pattern used for constructors that somewhat resembles this. "Telescoping Constructor Pattern" and using a "Builder Pattern" its not directly the same but kind of the same idea.